# Complaints that a route is missing while it's not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, controller, routes

I'm working on a very simple project management web app.

I have two different pages where you view the projects.

```
1. View all projects
2. View only the projects where you are administrator (includes buttons for editing / deletion of the projects)
```

Because I have two different pages for showing the projects I decided to create a custom route that directs the user to a custom action in the project controller.

However, this doesn't (by some reason) work, and I get the following error message:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"projects"}
```

**the view:**

```
<%= link_to "Manage projects", users_projects_path %>
```

**project controller:**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    ...
    def users_projects
      @users_projects = Project.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
    end
...
end
```

**project model:**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :class_name => 'User'

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tickets, :dependent => :destroy

  //validation

  attr_accessible :user_id, :title, :description, :start_date, :end_date
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are not giving an `id` parameter to the route, which is required.

Somewhere, you are generating a link to `edit_project_path`. Ensure that you are giving a project to that url generator: `edit_project_path(project)`

Comment: +1, for being an awesome Android person as myself... Oh, and the answer. That's good too. :)

Comment: Ok, but in this case I want to redirect the user to a page with all the projects (that the user owns), not a specific. How could that be done?

Comment: Does the error message happen when you are displaying the link or when someone clicks on it? My guess is that it is after someone clicks on it, thus it is the page that is displaying all the profiles throwing the error. It might help if you show your routes file and the full error trace message.